# Does a LazyLoaded Module dependant to a Root Level Import, requires importing the dependency?

Tags: angular

AppModule imports MatSnackBarModule.
On LazyModule I depend on MatSnackBarModule but I do not import it. This seems to be functional but is it correct?

I know that importing a module multiple times won't affect performance due to Tree-Shake effect, however I want to create an Abstract Service that will handle the MatSnackBar. If in the future I want to replace MatSnackBar I will only have to update the Abstract Service and just the import in the root module.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a `shared.module.ts` and import and export everything in there that is required in multiple modules. Then just import the `shared.module` in the different/other modules.  Every time something needs to be added/removed/changed it only needs to happen in one module.

Let's say:

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { foo } from 'bar';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        foo
    ],
    exports: [
        foo
    ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Then
**app.module.ts**

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule
    ]
})
```

Now, whenever something is added to the `shared.module`, it automatically gets added to all other modules that import it.

Comment: But is that adding any value, considering that my service currently works in my LazyModule only by importing its dependecy in the AppModule?

Comment: Maybe not now.  But other modules and services don't need to be imported by modules.  What you do need to import for example are components.  So components being used in multiple modules need to be imported by the module using it.  That is where a shared module comes in.  Angular Material is a great example of something being used in multiple modules.